# Some changes doesn't work on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I created a web site with .NET 4.0 . I published it to my server's IIS. My web site is working. But after publish when i tried to add new forms they work on Visual Studio's localhost but doesn't work on IIS . For example I create etik.aspx . It works on Visual Studio but when I deploy it to IIS It gives me this error.

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'BerksanWebSite.berknet.etik'.
```

Something else I add a change to my master page. It shows front changes (on aspx file) but changes in aspx.cs file doesn't work . I don't understand why it is not working. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with uploading new bin files to server. Thanks @Eldar

Answer (score 0):

Start from searching similar topics with same message

[Parser Error when deploy ASP.NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800550/parser-error-when-deploy-asp-net-application)

Try to push back your changes and find which one cause error.
May be find a video tutorial. Try again for empty project and simple form.