# Publish a visual studio project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have tried to publish my first Visual studio projet.

And I get this message:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type '_3rdDBhandin2.Index'.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="_3rdDBhandin2.Index" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html>

Source File: /3rdDBhandin/index.aspx    Line: 1
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212

Can someone help me, and tell what I have made wrong ?

Comment: Did you also publish the bin directory? Is the directory that you published to marked as an application? If not, ensure that it is marked as an application or else it will be looking for the dlls in the bin directory in a different location.

Comment: This is already answered here i guess.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800550/parser-error-when-deploy-asp-net-application