# Parsing error in distributing a Windows 10 app from an IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, msix, appx

I have created a Blazor Hybrid application and deploy it as a msix file.After i needed to distribute that app from my local iis server .i followed this link to do that
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/web-install-iis

but i am getting a error called "Error in parsing the package" when going to install
[image: Fig(1)]

what i have done over here is ,i have created a asp .net web application and created a folder called packages and included a my msix file and certificate file into it. and after i created a html file and included a link inorder to install that app.
after that i have created a virtual directory in my local iis and uploaded my project to that.
above issue(Fig(1)) is coming after run the app even thopugh app installler is opened .following you can see folder structure of mine.

[image: Fig(2)]

this is my index.html file

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title> Install Page </title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <a href="ms-appinstaller:?source=http://localhost/blapphoster/packages/BLMAUI_3.2.1.0_x64.msix"> Install My Sample App</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

i have added the this section to web.config

```
<system.webServer>
        <!--This is to allow the web server to serve resources with the appropriate file extension-->
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".appx" mimeType="application/appx" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".msix" mimeType="application/msix" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".appxbundle" mimeType="application/appxbundle" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".msixbundle" mimeType="application/msixbundle" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".appinstaller" mimeType="application/appinstaller" />
        </staticContent>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
```

am i doing any wrong thing here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't making virtual dir manualy and then copy app files here, Right-Click on your WebSite -> Properties, then in "Directory", Create your Application, Add it to your ApplicationPool and verify the virtual directory mounted. Then the bin directory should be seen and used.

More information you can refer to this link: [Parser Error when deploy ASP.NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800550/parser-error-when-deploy-asp-net-application).

Comment: i didnt create it manually.i created through visual studio itself .

Comment: Have you tried the other solutions in the link?